# .NET Minimal API middleware shortcutting returns just seems a poor code pattern. Am I missing something?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Consider for example this code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPost("/name", (string? name) => Results.Ok($"From endpoint: {name}")
   .AddEndpointFilter<NameEndpointFilter>();

app.Run();

public class NameEndpointFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(
        EndpointFilterInvocationContext context,
        EndpointFilterDelegate next
    )
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.GetRouteValue("name") is string name)
        {
            return Results.Problem($"From filter: {name}");
        }

        return await next(context);
    }
}
```

This sample was based on an online article that was near the top of a Google search on this topic.
The middleware (in this case a filter) is short-circuting the processing logic.
That to me smells like a GOTO statement. It also, in my opinion, doesn't seem very "minimal".

Do others dislike this pattern? I know that the sample is contrived and that I don't have to use this pattern, but most tutorials present somethign similar. Why is such short-curcuiting preferable to alternative patterns? Am I wrong to perceive this as a GOTO?

Comment: What article? What pattern? To solve what problem? If that's supposed to show how to validate requests it can be confusing as ASP.NET Core has its own validation middleware. Rejecting bad requests isn't a GOTO. If anything the sooner you reject an invalid request the better. An entire category of Denial-of-Service attacks sends invalid or very long parameters, trying to cause the server to either crash or freeze. You *want* to reject these as soon as possible, before you even start deserializing them

Comment: You could claim an authentication or authorization filter is also "short-circuiting" because it rejects invalid requests. It's not though. There's no point processing a request that's already failed authorization so why do it?

Comment: Besides, [Pipes-and-Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters) is one of the oldest and most common architectural patterns. You'll find it from shell pipelines all the way to distributed systems like Kafka to high performance dataflow systems. All web servers work this way. Instead of putting different concerns in a single method (authentication, validation, serialization, etc), you split them into tasks/filters that work on messages. Each filter does one job only, which allows them to be reused in different pipelines

Comment: I would claim that rejecting bad requests is a GOTO. But I'll also grant that it's an acceptable use case. And I'll grant that there are lots of acceptable use cases. My issue is that I see examples such as that which I posted, and I don't see examples that show it being used properly. So perhaps I'll just ask that. Any good examples?

Comment: You'd be wrong then and going against *all* high-powered web servers,  message-based distributed systems or data engineering projects. Even in functional languages [use function chaining and sidelining failures](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/). As for examples, every single ASP.NET Core application is a good example, as even minimal API projects have an entire pipeline of reusable filters.

Comment: In the [ASP.NET Core Middleware docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) check how many filters are used before your own controller is called. Those filters are used by every MVC or Razor Pages application without modifications. HSTS, HTTPS, Routing, authentication, authorization, response caching

Comment: PS: What article did you get this from? Searching for `NameEndpointFilter` doesn't return any results

Comment: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/aspnet-core-minimal-api-endpoint-filters

Comment: That article explains what filters are for and how/when they should be used. This snippet is just an API demonstration and a very small part of the full article

Comment: I disagree with that assessment. But in any case, I'm looking for a more real-world example of their use.

Comment: Did you read the Middleware docs? Aren't authentication, and the other concerns real-world? I suspect this isn't really a programming question but more about understanding what the pipes and filters, or pipeline architectural pattern is in general. You can claim an `if(object.IsValid){...}` is a GOTO too if you take this to extremes.

Comment: Yes. I wish to understand by looking at examples that aren't just showing syntax.

Answer (score 0):

While this particular case does not make much sense (I assume it is just an API demonstration), there are cases when it is just fine. It provides a nice way to encapsulate logic for [cross-cutting concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) applicable only to subset of endpoints (otherwise using middlewares would be arguably a better choice), very similar to [action filers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in ASP.NET Core (for example if there would be no default auth provided by framework it would be a nice option to implement it).

Comment: The [actual article](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/aspnet-core-minimal-api-endpoint-filters) is far longer than this snippet and does a good job of explaining what/why. The code is essentially an API demonstration, nothing more

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, that was my guess which I wanted to add but forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating 2 concepts here: middlewares, and filters.

What you are working with there is *not* a middleware, it is a filter. Filters are fired independently of middlewares, so you are not "short circuiting" at the middleware level, just at the filter level.

Each filter type has it's own "chain of responsibility", and one of the things you are freely allowed to do in a chain of responsibility is to "conditionally return early", which is what that implementation you have does.

The answer is thus "no", there is nothing wrong with returning early from a filter, since that's just short circuiting that specific filter type's pipeline and that's one of the things it was designed to support.

Also note that you are only short circuiting the Endpoint-type filter here. If you have exception filters, result filters, etc, those have their own separate pipelines (which can, also, be conditionally short circuited).

Comment: I'm looking at this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/min-api-filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0

One question I have (and I assume the answer is "yes" since otherwise the filter pipeline wouldn't be doing anything) is does the modification of the Todo object persisted to downstream steps: 

        var todo = efiContext.GetArgument<Todo>(0);
        todo.Name = todo.Name!.ToUpper();

Comment: I don't think I am conflating. Filters are handled by the internal RequestDelegate middleware.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington on the title of your question you specified "middleware shortcutting". The `IEndpointFilter` interface is not a middleware, it is a filter, and returning early from it does not shortcut the middleware pipeline (it has no effect on middlewares at all), it only shortcuts the endpoint filter chain of responsibility. This is where I think you are confusing the 2 concepts. I understand these filters will eventually run as part of one middleware (since middlewares are the execution units of the MVC pipeline), but that's beside the point.

Comment: Regarding the persistence question @ChrisHarrington, yes, changes in the context will propagate to further filters in the chain. This is the main mechanism that is used for result/change propagation from one filter to another and is again intended to be used that way.